Nginx config to nest webapp within subdirectory
I'm trying to configure Nginx pointing at a web app within a nested directory.
It's working fine in Apache with the following config:
Apache24:
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /nested "/var/www/html/nested/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/nested/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

http://myserver_name/nested/index.php >> OK!
Whereas the Nginx config keeps failing when using location /nested
Nginx: /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconf.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name myserver_name;
    root /var/www/html;

    index.php;
    
    location /nested {
        root /var/www/html/nested;
        
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
           # etc.
           # .
        }
    }
}

http://myserver_name/nested/index.php >> 'This site can’t be reached'.
Any idea how to configure Nginx to mirror the Apache config.
